# How to initiate a dict from a array with count?

Tags: python

Like, I have a array `[2, 3, 'a', 'wow', 3]`, is there some function from it I can get a dict which key is the item of list and value is the nubmer of time which appear? like `{2: 1, 3: 2, 'a': 1, 'wow': 1}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a counter:

```
>>> import collections
>>> print(collections.Counter([2, 3, 'a', 'wow', 3]))
Counter({3: 2, 'wow': 1, 2: 1, 'a': 1})
```